# How to change the name of a GridFS bucket in python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have been trying to figure out how to change the default name of a bucket while using GridFS in python. By default they look like,

```
fs.chunks
fs.files
```

I want them to look like,

```
custom.chunks
custom.files
```

Can anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, you just need to pass the name of the bucket with the argument. like this,
if your desired name for the bucket is custom,

```
GridFS(db, "Custom")
```